# What is the legal status of ferrets in the United States?

Tags: ferrets, united-states

I've heard that ferrets are illegal to own in some parts of the United States. I currently live in New Jersey but I'm planning to move in about a year and would like to know what my options are. Giving up my ferrets is not an option for me. Where is it illegal to own ferrets in the United States?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Legal Weasels FAQ](http://www.cypresskeep.com/Ferretfiles/Legal.htm),

Ferrets are legal in 48 of the United States but in the year 2000 California and Hawaii declared ferrets illegal. Also, some cities like New York, Dallas have their own laws restricting ferrets

So it is important to have a copy of the current animal control ordinance of the city you plan to move into.

Comment: Hawaii has some very strict controls on animal import, so not surprised.

Comment: Other than Hawaii and California, I think NYC and Washington DC are the only places where you cannot legally own a ferret. All other restrictions are on the sale and breeding of ferrets.